# Find out from JavaScript the unique ID of the blog's visitor (their Google account, GMail, etc)

Tags: javascript, unique, blogger, identification

QUESTION: how can I find out the id (I need only the unique account number in Google) of the Blogger.com visitor - if, of course, he is logged into the Google account (for example, via GMail)?

For example, here is a page from my blog: "http://ariturlearn.blogspot.com/2017/02/olurum-sana-69-1.html" which I can access in one of 3 roles:

- the author of the publication
- the author of the blog
- an visitor of the blog.

About publication author, the information is specified in the  tag containing the line
Href = "http://www.blogger.com/profile/06919529600336241866"

About author of the blog, the information is indicated in the  tag containing the line
Href = "https://www.blogger.com/profile/06919529600336241866"

And, finally, about a blog visitor, the information is specified in the  tag or, more precisely, in the embedded  tag. There is a  containing the string "id = av-06919529600336241866"

Here the code (06919529600336241866) is the same in all three places, because I am all in once: the visitor, the author of the blog, and the author of the article.

If I enter a blog by another user, for example rom130811, then in  will already be "id = av-15717291175351401715"

Unfortunately I can not read this visitor code in JavaScript. But I can only see it in browser's developer mode. 
And if I really need to read them? 
Help me, please, how to get this (15717291175351401715) id code using JavaScript within Blog's page

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the comment form (which contains visitor identity when they are logged in) is loaded via an `iframe` into the page, it is not possible to access it via JavaScript due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) being applied by web browsers. Refer to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important) to understand this concept better

A more practical way to get information about the visitor would be to implement **Google Sign In for Websites** - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference. That way, those users that explicitly sign-in via it, their information (including name, email, etc) would be accessible to you.

Comment: Thank Prayag! It will be good solution. I work on them and lately will decribe it details in by blog.